# Angular Formly form used both as edit [input field] and read only [display field as in Extjs]

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-formly

I want to achieve a functionality where I will use the same form created using Angular Formly in edit mode as a text field and in read only mode as label which only shows data not a textbox

Comment: You want to use them in two different pages? Or you want this to happen like when you click on a button which locks the text filed write operation?

Answer (score 1):

I would make a [custom template](http://docs.angular-formly.com/docs/custom-templates) like this (based on [bootstrap templates](https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly-templates-bootstrap)):

```
formlyConfig.setType({
  name: 'readonly',
  extends: 'input',
  wrapper: ['bootstrapLabel', 'bootstrapHasError'],
  template: '<span class="my-readonly-field" ng-model="model[options.key]">',
});
```

See example jsbin: http://jsbin.com/jevobil/1/edit?css,js,console,output